# Python Authentication

Tags: python, authentication

I'm new to python and after struggling with myself a little bit I almost got the code to working.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypass'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login = urllib.urlencode({'user' : username, 'pass' : password})
opener.open('http://www.ok.com/', login)
mailb = opener.open('http://www.ok.com/mailbox').read()
print mailb
```

But the output I got after print is just a redirect page.

```
<html>

<head>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=https://login.ok.com/login.html?skin=login-page&dest=REDIR|http://www.ok.com/mailbox">

<HTML dir=ltr><HEAD><TITLE>OK :: Redirecting</TITLE>

</head>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can now use this `cj` to browse website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a browser got that response, it would interpret it as a request to redirect to the URL specified.

You will need to do something similar with your script.  You need to parse the `<META>` tag and locate the URL and then do a GET on that URL.

Comment: At last it worked, thanks. I also think I were a bit lucky. if I tried the same thing in another website, it could have not worked. it will always output the redirect page first ? I can always rely on this method ?

Comment: @sophiaw, Who knows what ok.com will do?  They're under no obligation to continue showing a redirect on login.  It is up to you to continue testing your app to ensure it works with the current version of ok.com.

Comment: @S.Lott, thanks for the edit, that's much more helpful to the OP.